# Displaying a time vector with the same unit

Tags: r, time

```
a1 = Sys.time()
(job1)
a2 = Sys.time()
t1 = a2 - a1
b1 = Sys.time()
(job2)
b2 = Sys.time()
t2 = b2 - b1
c(t1,t2)
```

When I compare computation times for two jobs, I use the above commands.
They are basically displayed in 'seconds' unit, but some elements are changed to 'minutes' unit if it is greater than 10,000 seconds.
How can I control this time unit?

Comment: `as.numeric(c(t1, t2), units = "secs")`?

Comment: You could use `difftime()` as well. `t1 <- difftime(a2, a1, units = "secs")`.  Just always use `secs`